# Meaning of "the lady be young and fair"

Tags: meaning

> I whispered, “I am too young,”
>   And then, “I am old enough”;
>   Wherefore I threw a penny
>   To find out if I might love.
>   “Go and love, go and love, young man,
>   If the lady be young and fair.”
>
> —William Butler Yeats, “Brown Penny”

What's the meaning of "If the lady be young and fair.”

"be" is like "is"?

Comment: You should look through our [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners/4797). It has great tips to help you format your question and give it a fitting title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, **if the lady be young and fair** means **If the lady is young and pretty**.